# Glassfish domain reported as not running although it is started

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I’m using glassfish 3.1.2 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga). Glassfish has been installed as part of a piece of bigger software (that I’m developing). It used to work correctly in the past.

I can issue a ‘start-domain’ command. This one will work correctly and glassfish will start. I can see the process and the glassfish admin web console is working fine. However, the command ‘list-domain’ reports my domain as not running. The command ‘stop-domain’ will fail reporting the domain1 as already stopped. This prevents my software to run properly.

As far as I know, nothing has changed on that system. There is no exception/error in the log. I already search the internet for description of similar behaviour. I ensured the embedded firewall (the one coming with the OS) did not prevent the communication. I removed the expired certificate (just in case). I have no idea on what I could do next.

What could I check? Any help appreciated. Add a comment if you need specific details and I will update the question.

Answer to unwichtich's questions:

1. absolute path to jvm using an absolute path to the admin-cli.jar: /.../java -Duser.home=... -Duser.language=en -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -jar /.../glassfish/modules/admin-cli.jar --terse --port 23992 --user admin --passwordfile /.../passwordfile list-domains
2. There are two lines in the /etc/hosts. The first with the ip mapping to the hostname. The second with 127.0.0.1 mapping to loopback and localhost
3. My software includes some command line utilities that need to perform operation on Glassfish (like start-domain, stop-domain, list-domains,...).

Comment: How exactly are you using the `asadmin` commands (absolute or relative path)? Also make sure, the hostname returned by the `hostname` command matches the one which is mapped to `127.0.0.1` in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Why are you using `asadmin` via Java instead of using it directly?